# Keep firing function after Ionic routes to page?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic project using tabs.

On my tab I have the following:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" (ionSelect)="toggleCompare();" tabTitle="Compare"></ion-tab>
```

When I click this it correctly takes me back to the root page, and then runs my toggleCompare function, which is inside my tabs.ts...

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) {
    this._appGlobals.showCompare.subscribe(value => this.compare = value);
}

toggleCompare() {
    this.compare = !this.compare;
    this._appGlobals.showCompare.next(this.compare);
}
```

Which again on click coming from another page works absolutely fine. The problem I have is that if you go to click the button again the page does absolutely nothing. No refresh, not running of the function.

Can anyone suggest a better way of toggling but also routing back to the page if the user is not already on it?

Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the `toggleCompare()` to run ONLY when the user goes to that page or do you want it to run everytime the user clicks on this tab?

Comment: @GabrielWabiz I'd like it to run on whatever page you're on. The idea is that you click the tab, if you're on another page it routes you back to the page the compare element is on and then opens it. But if you're already on the page, it just opens the compare element and doesn't do any routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some extensive digging I came to the conclusion that the ion-tabs were the blocker in achieving the result I desired. I ripped them out and made my own tabs using the side menu template provided by Ionic. This fixed my issue and now the tabs swap out dynamically.